# Crystal report remove white space between two words

Tags: crystal-reports, whitespace, desktop-application, crystal-reports-2010

I am using Crystal Report 10.5 in my desktop application. When i run application, it will show the crystal report with proper data. In some words, it put proper white space between two words. But in some case it will remove white space between the words.

i.e. This is the sentence:  "**Name with 03/02/1978 and 4 days**".

Now when it will print in Crystal report, it shows "**Name with 03/02/1978 and4 days**". Crystal report removes space before "**4 days**".

I dont know why crystal report is behaving like this. In some place it will print correctly and in some place it creates problem.

So can any one tell me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is totally one string? or you are concatenating two words?

Comment: This might not happen please check if the string is proper. Text alignment should be proper of a text object, I hope its not justified.